# Why do trees sway?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

> Resonance can also occur in three dimensions (such as wind induced swaying)

I tried to make a free body diagram (I know it is terribly wrong) to find the forces that causes the tree to undergo simple harmonic motion. But it is of no use.

Wind keeps constantly blowing and applying constant force on the tree and there must be the opposite and restoring force that leads to simple harmonic motion of the tree, which I cannot find.

Can some one explain to me **how trees sway due to wind** and **what relation of swaying has with resonance**?

[image]

Comment: Because the wind blows?

Comment: i don't think that the tree would sway if  wind blows **constantly**. But if there is an increase and decrease in wind speed (which is applicable to real world) then for sure we can see the swaying motion of tree.

Comment: Er, how about stresses and strains of the trunk as the source of restoring forces?

Comment: @KyleKanos - Exactly. Do schools not teach about the Tacoma Narrows Bridge anymore?